# How to write to a file in a recoverable (transactional) way?

Tags: c++, windows, file, storage, ntfs

I have files on disk that contain critical information that needs to be updated every so often. It's safe to assume that only one process accesses that file, that the app is running on Windows and on an NTFS file system.

My goal is to prevent possible data corruption (partial write, for example) in case of program crashes, power outage, etc. In this question, I'm not concerned with disk sector corruption.

This is my current approach:

On write:

- Write new data in a temporary file.
- Create a voucher file. (This file guarantees that the temporary file has valid contents.)
- Write new data in the target file.
- Delete the voucher file.
- Delete the temporary file.

On read:

- If the voucher file exists:

  - Copy the temporary file to the target file.
  - Delete the voucher file.
- Read the target file.
- Delete the temporary file, if it exists.

Questions:

- With my current approach, if I'm overwriting only a few bytes of the file, if it is possible for other bytes to erroneously change as a result of some failure?
- With my current approach, is it neccessary to disable file caching, or does Windows reliably recover the cache in case of power outage?
- Is there a faster approach, by using some knowledge of how either Windows or NTFS work? If so, I would be interested if there are any differences on FAT file systems.

I'm aware of the transactional NTFS API in Win32, but I don't want to use it since it's deprecated.

Comment: Use sqlite or another rdb.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That's horribly overkill.

Comment: you want corruption safety; databases are known for their robustness and recovery options and they have transactions.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Of course, but they are also not a reasonable solution for storing 1 file. Instead of using a database, I should do whatever databases do to be robust.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Besides, I don't just want to get this working, I also want to know how and why it works.

Comment: In that case the question is too broad for here.